# Opacity out of range (negative) in Raphaël

Tags: javascript, raphael, max

I have a page that is throwing a JavaScript exception:

```
Unhandled exception at line 5144, column 13 in raphael.js
0x80048270 - JavaScript runtime error: Arg: Fraction out of range (0 to 1 allowed)
```

I'm using version 2.1.0 of Raphaël, and for debugging purposes using the uncompressed JavaScript file not the minimized one (i.e. the one copied from http://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/raw/master/raphael.js)

If I break into a debugger (I'm using Visual Studio 2012) I find that the value of the variable 'opacity' is -0.23185589076263113 while it should be between 0 and 1. But I cannot see how it got to be negative. Here's the code (from raphael.js, i.e. it's library code not my code)

```
        opacity = mmin(mmax(opacity, 0), 1);
        params["stroke-width"] == null && (width = a["stroke-width"]);
        params["stroke-width"] && (stroke.weight = width);
        width && width < 1 && (opacity *= width) && (stroke.weight = 1);
        stroke.opacity = opacity;
```

How can opacity == -0.23185589076263113 on the last line of this code when the first line clearly limits it to [0, 1]?

(N.B. in raphael.js mmax is math.max and mmin is math.min.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.

```
width && width < 1 && (opacity *= width) && (stroke.weight = 1);
```

is breaking the opacity range if width is negative (which in this case it is). Width is set on the line before the block I quoted (5139):

```
var width = (toFloat(params["stroke-width"]) || 1) * .75;
```

I need to debug my code to find out why params["stroke-width"] is negative and I've suggested that Raphael guards against that: https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/issues/623